# emacs/LaTeX error for first time LaTeX user

Tags: emacs, latex

I am using LaTeX with Emacs for the first time. I am getting the following error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted
```

This is the code I put in:

```
center\[
$$Q(t) = Pi a^2 \sqrt{2gh}$$
```

]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you would like to achieve something like the following:

```
\[
Q(t) = \Pi a^2 \sqrt{2gh}
\]
```

I replaced the $$ in your code with `\[` and `\]` respectively. Please see e.g. [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for some detailed explanations on why the use of `\[` and `\]` is preferable to `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: However, I do agree with @jjlin that tex.stackexchange.com would be a better place for your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a single '$' at each side.  Although if you're trying to center the equation anyway, your best bet would be to use

```
\begin{equation*}
Q(t) = \Pi a^2 \sqrt{2gh}
\end{equation*}
```

This will center it on its own line, and the * simply says not to number the equation.